# module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'xaxis'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

So I'm very new to Python and I'm having the following issue: I want to display a boxplot but everytime I'm trying to name the axis or yaxis I'm getting the following error: AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'xaxis'
I would appreciate some help as I have no idea whats causing this. Other than the error, the boxplot does show correctly.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
myFile = pd.read_csv("myFile.csv", sep=";")
data_to_plot = [myFile.Class_1,myFile.Class_2]
plt.boxplot(data_to_plot)
plt.xaxis("X - Axis")
plt.yaxis("Y - Axis")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you mind to provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: `pandas`  already include `matplotlib` funcionalities. In my answer you got a pandas only solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're probably looking for is

```
plt.xlabel('X - axis')
plt.ylabel('Y - axis')
```

The error is telling you that the attribute doesn't exist and so you can't access plt.xaxis

Comment: I tried that, it gives me "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" and pointing to the newly inserted lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here a reproducible example

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4),
                  columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4'])
boxplot = df.boxplot(column=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])
boxplot.set_xlabel("X - axis")
boxplot.set_ylabel("Y - axis");
```